# blockchain nodes that dont get the new block

Tags: blockchain, mining-theory, nodes, peers

i read somewhere that after 40 second of creating a new block in the blockchain there's still 5% of the nodes that does not have the block, what happens to them if they were offline or down at that moment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> what happens to (those nodes) if they were offline or down at that moment?

When each of those nodes comes back online, it will re-connect to other nodes on the network, and request data from those nodes about the most recent blocks. Each node will then validate that data for itself, and once that is finished, the node will be back in sync with the network.

Comment: is it possible for you to give me your email address? I just started research in this area and I need a couple of resources.

Comment: The best resource for understanding how nodes operate is just the source code that the majority of nodes on the network run: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin. I don't share any email addresses here, sorry. There is a site chat room though: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8089/mempool